# Run function only on page load/refresh, and not when app mounts via route change

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to load an animation via useEffect when a page is loaded, but I only want to run the function on load/reload and not when the user routes back into the page. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

useEffect always triggers at first render that's its behaviour therefor it is not possible

Answer (score 0):

Pass some param in the url when changing route then check that param and call the function accordingly.